# Xcode 5 Undefined symbols for architecture i386 After Updating Google Analytics to 3.0.1

Tags: ios, xcode, google-analytics

After updating Google Analytics to 3.0.1 in Xcode 5 I now get this error when building for the simulator. Device builds don't have this problem though.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_llvm_gcda_emit_arcs", referenced from:
    ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAPDK.a(GAITrackerImpl.o)
    ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAPDK.a(GAIBatchingDispatcher.o)
    ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAPDK.a(GAIRequestBuilder.o)
    ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAPDK.a(GAIUtil.o)
    ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAPDK.a(GAIDefaultLogger.o)
    ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAPDK.a(GAIDataStore.o)
    ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAPDK.a(GAIHitUtil.o)
    ...
"_llvm_gcda_emit_function", referenced from:
    ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAPDK.a(GAITrackerImpl.o)
    ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAPDK.a(GAIBatchingDispatcher.o)
    ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAPDK.a(GAIRequestBuilder.o)
    ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAPDK.a(GAIUtil.o)
    ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAPDK.a(GAIDefaultLogger.o)
    ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAPDK.a(GAIDataStore.o)
    ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAPDK.a(GAIHitUtil.o)
    ...
"_llvm_gcda_end_file", referenced from:
    ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAPDK.a(GAITrackerImpl.o)
    ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAPDK.a(GAIBatchingDispatcher.o)
    ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAPDK.a(GAIRequestBuilder.o)
    ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAPDK.a(GAIUtil.o)
    ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAPDK.a(GAIDefaultLogger.o)
    ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAPDK.a(GAIDataStore.o)
    ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAPDK.a(GAIHit.o)
    ...
"_llvm_gcda_increment_indirect_counter", referenced from:
    -[GAITrackerImpl gai_set:value:] in libAPDK.a(GAITrackerImpl.o)
    -[GAITrackerImpl gai_get:] in libAPDK.a(GAITrackerImpl.o)
    -[GAITrackerImpl gai_send:] in libAPDK.a(GAITrackerImpl.o)
    -[GAIBatchingDispatcher batchBySessionSplit:maxHits:] in libAPDK.a(GAIBatchingDispatcher.o)
    -[GAIBatchingDispatcher hitsForDispatch] in libAPDK.a(GAIBatchingDispatcher.o)
    -[GAIBatchingDispatcher nextPendingHits] in libAPDK.a(GAIBatchingDispatcher.o)
    -[GAIBatchingDispatcher queueDispatch:] in libAPDK.a(GAIBatchingDispatcher.o)
    ...
"_llvm_gcda_start_file", referenced from:
    ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAPDK.a(GAITrackerImpl.o)
    ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAPDK.a(GAIBatchingDispatcher.o)
    ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAPDK.a(GAIRequestBuilder.o)
    ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAPDK.a(GAIUtil.o)
    ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAPDK.a(GAIDefaultLogger.o)
    ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAPDK.a(GAIDataStore.o)
    ___llvm_gcov_writeout in libAPDK.a(GAIHit.o)
    ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**Update**

I am starting to think that the .a file provided by Google may not have the i386 arc. The problem started after updating from v3.0 to 3.0.1.

Comment: take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949781/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-upgrading-project-to-ios-5

Comment: I had already found that question and tried the suggestions.

Comment: Yes- facing the same issue. Works on device builds but fails for simulators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't remember what version fixed this but it does work in the current `3.06` version. If you are running into this problem try updating the SDK.